# Extracting an email address that matches the domain name between cells with REGEXTRACT in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a full URL in A1 and in B1 there are various comma seperated data alongside an email address in random order. How can I extract the comma based email using the contents and relation of cell A1?

I have managed to strip out the bare domain with the code below into C1
`=trim(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"https?://",""),"^(w{3}\.)?","")&"/","([^/?]+)"))`

How can REGEXRACT be used in B1 to pull out the email address? Mostly the emails are domain based, but can also use the main part of the domain with a Gmail or Outlook address ie. acmecorp@gmail.com

Here is the Google Sheet example (your own copy can be made using File-Make a Copy)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vnC2r_IdbLuoEBn3FO5as5frS_EZ-_5HuSubRF50Hd0/edit?usp=sharing

It could also be achived by extracting a comma value that has .com or .co.uk in it

Comment: Try `=REGEXEXTRACT(B2, REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "://([^.]+)") & "@[^,\s]+|[^,\s@]+@" & REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "://([^.]+)") & "[^,\s]*")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Wiktor (comments above) and I were on a similar line of thought. But try this. Clear an entire column (including the top/header cell) and place this formula into the top cell of that otherwise empty column:

`=ArrayFormula({"HEADER OF CHOICE";IF(A2:A="",,IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B,"([^,]*"&REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"://([^\.]+)")&"[^,]*)")))})`

You can change the header title within the formula as you like.

This one array formula will process the entire column.